# Can I upload an external URL containing a lot of data to App Engine blob store?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url, upload

I'd like to upload external images (for which I have the URL) into the Blobstore.  I *can't* post the data, as its on another web site.

Its straightforward to upload by (a) using the fetch service to fetch the URL and then (b) using the file service to store the data from the URL as a blob.  However this requires loading the data into my running instance.  As I understand the fetch service all the data has to reside in memory before it can be uploaded, which restricts the maximum data size.  If the fetch service streamed data that wouldn't be too bad.

Does anyone know a way I can copy an external image into a blob in a memory-efficient way?

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server supports it, you can download the file in chunks. Usually, servers indicate this by sending the **[Accept-Ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5)** header. You can request a specific byte range by setting the **[Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2)** header. If the server accepts this and only serves the specified byte range, it sends the **[Content-Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16)** header with the request.

In theory, you should then be able to keep appending to the file object, until you finalize it.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like the best that can be done. Not sure how many sites implement ranges.  For instance Flickr does but Picasa doesn't, as far as I can see.